# Unform não retorna o erro de validação

Tags: css, typescript, react-native

Pessoal estou desenvolvendo um app e utilizando o `unform` da **Rocketseat** para validação de formulários.
Porém ao tentar criar um erro de validação exibindo a borda do componente em vermelho caso esteja vazio, o erro retorna na tela de **signIn** porém quando tento 'setar' ele pelo `formRef` ele não está enviando e acaba retornando para o input como se não tivesse erro algum. Alguém poderia me ajudar, estou deixando algo passar.

O **Focused** está funcionando certinho, o problema está no erro quando setado pelo **formRef** `formRef.current?.setErrors(errors);`

Quando o recupero esse **useField** em input ele não retorna o erro `const { registerField, defaultValue = '', fieldName, error } = useField(name);`

**SignIn**

```
interface SignInFormData {
  email_user: string;
  password_user: string;
}

const SignIn: React.FC = () => {
  const formRef = useRef<FormHandles>(null);
  const passwordInputRef = useRef<TextInput>(null);

  const navigation = useNavigation();

  const handleSignIn = useCallback(async (data: SignInFormData) => {
    try {
      formRef.current?.setErrors({});

      const schema = Yup.object().shape({
        email_user: Yup.string()
          .required('E-mail obrigatório')
          .email('Digite um e-mail válido'),
        password_user: Yup.string().required('Senha obrigatória'),
      });

      await schema.validate(data, {
        abortEarly: false,
      });

    } catch (err) {
      if (err instanceof Yup.ValidationError) {
        const errors = getValidationErrors(err);

        formRef.current?.setErrors(errors);

        return;
      }

      Alert.alert(
        'Erro na Autenticação',
        'Ocorrou um erro ao fazer login, cheque as credenciais.',
      );
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <KeyboardAvoidingView
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
        behavior={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'padding' : undefined}
        enabled
      >
        <ScrollView
          keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled"
          contentContainerStyle={{ flex: 1 }}
        >
          <Container>
            <Image source={logoImg} />

            <View>
              <Title>Faça seu Logon</Title>
            </View>

            <Form ref={formRef} onSubmit={handleSignIn}>
              <Input
                autoCorrect={false}
                autoCapitalize="none"
                keyboardType="email-address"
                name="email"
                icon="mail"
                placeholder="E-mail"
                returnKeyType="next"
                onSubmitEditing={() => {
                  passwordInputRef.current?.focus();
                }}
              />

              <Input
                ref={passwordInputRef}
                name="password"
                icon="lock"
                placeholder="Senha"
                secureTextEntry
                returnKeyType="send"
                onSubmitEditing={() => {
                  formRef.current?.submitForm();
                }}
              />

              <Button
                onPress={() => {
                  formRef.current?.submitForm();
                }}
              >
                Entrar
              </Button>
            </Form>

            <ForgotPassword onPress={() => ({})}>
              <ForgotPasswordText>Esqueci minha senha</ForgotPasswordText>
            </ForgotPassword>
          </Container>
        </ScrollView>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>

      <CreateAccountButton onPress={() => navigation.navigate('SignUp')}>
        <Icon name="log-in" size={20} color="#e4a608" />
        <CreateAccountButtonText>Criar conta</CreateAccountButtonText>
      </CreateAccountButton>
    </>
  );
};

export default SignIn;
```

**Input**

```
interface InputProps extends TextInputProps {
  name: string;
  icon: string;
}

interface InputValueReference {
  value: string;
}

interface InputRef {
  focus(): void;
}

const Input: React.ForwardRefRenderFunction<InputRef, InputProps> = (
  { name, icon, ...rest },
  ref,
) => {
  const inputElementRef = useRef<any>(null);

  const { registerField, defaultValue = '', fieldName, error } = useField(name);
  const inputValueRef = useRef<InputValueReference>({ value: defaultValue });

  const [isFocused, setIsFocused] = useState(false);
  const [isFilled, setIsFilled] = useState(false);

  const handleInputFocus = useCallback(() => {
    setIsFocused(true);
  }, []);

  const handleInputBlur = useCallback(() => {
    setIsFocused(false);

    setIsFilled(!!inputValueRef.current.value);
  }, []);

  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    focus() {
      inputElementRef.current.focus();
    },
  }));

  useEffect(() => {
    registerField<string>({
      name: fieldName,
      ref: inputValueRef.current,
      path: 'value',
    });
  }, [fieldName, registerField]);

  return (
    <Container isFocused={isFocused} isErrored={!!error}>
      <Icon
        name={icon}
        size={20}
        color={isFocused || isFilled ? '#e4a608' : '#666360'}
      />

      <TextInput
        ref={inputElementRef}
        keyboardAppearance="dark"
        placeholderTextColor="#666360"
        defaultValue={defaultValue}
        onFocus={handleInputFocus}
        onBlur={handleInputBlur}
        onChangeText={(value) => {
          inputValueRef.current.value = value;
        }}
        {...rest}
      />
    </Container>
  );
};

export default forwardRef(Input);
```

**CSS Input**

```
interface ContainerProps {
  isFocused: boolean;
  isErrored: boolean;
}

export const Container = styled.View<ContainerProps>`
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 0 16px;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: #ffffff;

  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;

  ${(props) =>
    props.isErrored &&
    css`
      border-color: #ff0000;
    `}

  ${(props) =>
    props.isFocused &&
    css`
      border-color: #e4a608;
    `}
`;
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

consegui resolver o problema, foi um erro básico meu. Minha *interface* **SignInFormData** possui os atributos **email_user** e **password_user**, porém no *Form* do meu **SignIn** eu passei os nomes sem a implementação do **_user**. Então só foi alterar o *name* para **email_user** e **password_user**. E o problema foi resolvido.